# stopping service or killing his process?

Tags: c#, powershell, service, process

I can't find any clear answer to what is the difference between:

- stopping a service with a stop action

and

- killing a process to make it stop?

Killing a process is faster than stopping the service, but I don't know if it can create some problemes?

Comment: Have a look at this answer. Killing the process is the part when you're chased by the police and gunned down: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159457/do-i-need-to-terminate-task-in-windows-service-in-onstop-method/15159601#15159601

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would you like to go to sleep naturally, or would you rather someone punch you in the face and knock you out? :)

Stopping a service allows it to shut down in a meaningful fashion, perhaps write some log entries and do all manner of things.

Killing a process doesn't allow any of this.  Blam, you're dead.  Hardly elegant.

Comment: ok :) so the better way is to try to stop the service then kill the process if the service doesn't stop ?

Comment: @usopp, can you look in to why the service isn't stopping?

Comment: i need to make a script in powershell (remote wmi) who restart a service because the process of the service freeze but not the service on a 2003 without powershell..
so many its the frozen process who can block the service ?

Answer (score 2):

The relationship between a process and service is not guaranteed to be 1:1. That is, there are processes that host multiple services - most prominently `svchost.exe`, which not only exists as multiple instances, but each instance hosts multiple services.

While `svchost.exe` is a component of Windows, the same is also true for services provided by third party vendors. In .NET, for example, you can see that the [ServiceBase.Run()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6esb073b.aspx) method even accepts multiple `ServiceBase` instances (i.e. service implementations) to start.

So, if you kill the process that hosts a service, you may terminate more service than just the one you had in mind. Be careful.